# Fragments with empty constructors vs. newInstance

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, instantiation

If I am creating a Fragment class, I've seen written everywhere that it is a good idea to include an empty constructor (although I'm not sure why, because I always assumed Java had an empty constructor invoked under the hood for any Java class as long as you don't create a constructor with arguments, and Android doesn't like you making Fragments with constructors with arguments anyway).

But if I am making a newInstance() method (so I can set up my Bundle with default arguments), do I have to create the empty constructor?

If it is enough to include newInstance() and not an empty constructor, could I do this for all my fragments even if there are no arguments in the bundle? Is there any downside to this?

Comment: no downside..infact newInstance() enforces a factory pattern...which will become useful when you want to change or refactor your code later.

Comment: Do I still need the empty constructor? Why do I need to include it?

Comment: no you won't need empty constructor

Comment: "I always assumed Java had an empty constructor invoked under the hood for any Java class as long as you don't create a constructor with arguments" -- correct. "could I do this for all my fragments even if there are no arguments in the bundle?" -- you could if you wanted. I'd just call `new WhateverFragment()`. You do not need to implement a zero-argument public constructor; you just inherit it.

Comment: @KaliMa if you want to follow the standard of initializing a fragment then go with newInstance, Specially if you want to send some data to the fragment when you are initializing it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Are you saying I am actually mistaken in my assumption that I need to explicitly make an empty constructor (such as writing `public FragmentName(){}`) for Fragments if I am not using newInstance()?

Comment: My confusion stems from this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html "All subclasses of Fragment must include a public no-argument constructor. The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed, in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this constructor to instantiate it. If the no-argument constructor is not available, a runtime exception will occur in some cases during state restore. " I do not understand why Fragments are different from any other Java class where the constructor is handled automatically

Comment: Correct -- you are mistaken in your assumption. If you do not implement a public zero-argument constructor, you inherit one from the superclass. See [this sample fragment](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Fragments/Dynamic/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/dfrag/OtherFragment.java)  "My confusion stems from this" -- yes, the documentation sucks.

Comment: So in short, I don't have to write the empty constructor, and I can write the `newInstance()` method if I want to get in a practice of setting up expected arguments to be received in (e.g.) the `onCreateView()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When making a static `getInstance()` method you'll be using that method to get a new instance of that `Fragment`. You wont be needing an empty constructor.

Comment: Why is the empty constructor a good idea if I decided not to use newInstance()? Why is this somehow different from normal Java classes where empty constructors are automatically handled?